# UIbutton click issue - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, storyboard

I'm trying to add login button overlap on subview, the touch event for uibutton does not work on lower-half.
[image]

Can anyone provide me an idea to achieve design like this, with touch event work on all corner ?

Comment: you have to remove button from parent view and set above blue view

Comment: it is inside blue view only

Comment: You have to keep button outside the UIView otherwise it is not tappable. Maintain the position of button according to UIView by using constraints.

Comment: @Indrajeet touches on edges also not working

Comment: @US-1234 did you try solution, what I mention in above comment? It will solve your problem

Comment: @Indrajeet It works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You view set up should look something like:

[image]

As **Inderjeet** mentioned in his comment, *"You have to keep button outside the `UIView` otherwise it is not tap-able. Maintain the position of button according to `UIView` by using constraints."*

Now to answer why, set *clip to bounds* property of your `view` to true. You will see, on run time, portion which is not tap-able, is also not visible.